# Basic encryption to authenticate users

Tags: algorithm, encryption

I'm writing a web service and I need to make sure only valid applications will use it (before I start managing a session for their users).

In order to achieve that I thought of using asymmetric key algorithm, but I'm not really sure how - what data to encrypt, how to manage the keys, etc. (my web service's data isn't **that** sensitive, I'm just trying to block casual trouble-makers).

Side note: I'm using .NET and found this class-  [RSACryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as0w18af.aspx) to be useful, but any framework independent idea would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: @Henk - I'm not sure. ur's solution looks ok (still need to consider it) or I can ask the programmers of the application that use my web service to apply some algorithm we both agree on, or something like that, but maybe that's too much fuss for my specs..

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you mean by "password". Provide them with a string that they should send upon the first request? But that's easy to forge - anyone can send that string.

Comment: The advantage is - If a malicious user observes what is sent from his app just twice and sees that password - he tries to send it on his own - and he's in. If he sees a bunch of bytes his application receives and another bunch his application sends and try to mimic that on the next bunch of bytes, he needs to work A LOT to forge it. What am I missing here?

Comment: ...I'm worried about being able to forge the handshake. IMO eavesdropping is one of the easiest ways to (try to) accomplish that.

Comment: HTTP headers sent from his app for example. (Fiddler\Firebug\whatever)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, your web service could send a random value of some bytes (challenge) and expect a valid answer for it (response). 
E.g. the response could be the SHA256 digest for the challenge and some secret bytes embedded in the application (salt). 
.NET-Code sample [here](http://www.obviex.com/samples/Code.aspx?Source=HashCS&Title=Hashing%20Data&Lang=C%23).